# automated alert emails using sql developer

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, oracle11g

A supermarket has many products.  When one of these products reaches a quantity of zero an automated email needs to be sent to the manager, showing that this product is out of stock.

I have done the email part( sending email through SQL Developer ).  Now I  need to set up a loop  to keep tracking the products' quantity.  How is this loop called? .

APC? i tried this out. but its not working for me

```
create or replace
procedure check_stock_qty
begin      
for r in ( select product_name,product_id from super_market 
where pro_qty = 0 )  
loop       
UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'blabla@me.com',
        recipients => 'blabla@me.com',
         subject => 'Test Mail',
         message => ( r.product_name ),
      mime_type => 'text; charset=us-ascii');  

end loop; 
end;
------------------------
BEGIN    

dbms_scheduler.create_job (job_name => 'stock check',
job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',        
job_action      => 'BEGIN check_stock_qty; END;',    
start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,       
repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; interval=5; bysecond=0;',    
end_date        => NULL,         
enabled    => TRUE,
END;
```

the procedure compiled, but win run it. it gives an error " the selected program is in an invalid state for running. recompile the program and try again "

Comment: Are you intending to send one email for each product that is out of stock every five minutes? Better to build a list of out-of-stock products and send that, I'd think. You'd probably also want to store a list of recent notifications so that you don't notify on the same item every five minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be to use a database job to periodically check the PRODUCTS table.

First of all you need a stored procedure.  Something like this:

```
create or replace procedure check_stock_qty
begin
     for r in ( select product_name from products
                where qty = 0 )
     loop
         your_email_proc_here ( r.product_name );
     end loop;
end;
```

You would then set this to run at regular intervals.  As you're using Oracle 11g you should use the DBMS_SCHEDULER API to do this.  This calll will run the above stock checker every five minutes:

```
BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_job (
        job_name        => 'stock check',
        job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action      => 'BEGIN check_stock_qty; END;',
        start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
        repeat_interval => 'freq=minutely; interval=5; bysecond=0;',
        end_date        => NULL,
        enabled         => TRUE,
END;
/
```

DBMS_SCHEDULER is pretty sophisticated i.e. complicated but it is well documented.  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm)